# SQL Restore DB frozen at 100% [SQL SERVER 2008 R2]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is the second time I've restored my DB and it freezes at 100% not sure why.

```
10 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
70 percent processed.
80 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
100 percent processed.
Processed 16305440 pages for database 'db1', file 'db1' on file 1.
Processed 74479 pages for database 'db1', file 'db1_log' on file 1.
```

I've tried using the console for restoring and also running the command directly into the window and it stays at 100%, it took 63m to completely restore and now is being sometime since then.

```
session_id  command Percent Complete    ETA Completion Time Elapsed Min ETA Min ETA Hours
61  RESTORE DATABASE    100.00  2017-11-13 16:02:54 69  0.00    0.00
```

What is going on?

```
RESTORE DATABASE [db1] FROM  DISK = N'D:\DATA\db1.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'db1' TO N'D:\DATA\db1.mdf',  MOVE N'db1_log' TO N'D:\DATA\db1_1.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

SQL SERVER 2008 R2

[image: progress status]

Comment: what do you mean by `freezes at 100%`? the db is showing `Restoring` status and cannot be accessed? try to `Restore database name with recovery`

Comment: On the database menu it still says restoring, while I execute the command to check the progress status it says 100% completed.

Comment: Try the command above, you are just restoring the `.bak`, I assume the 1st file is the databse file, and after you executed your query, it is waiting for the `Transaction logs backup`, if you do not recovery that backup file, you could bring the database back to access by using `Restore database name with recovery`

Comment: Here is the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/fEQ90pP.png

Comment: I can see  the three files (x1 mdf, x1 ndf, x1 ldf)

Comment: these are just database files, you can ignore those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, after restoring a database backup file without restoring the transaction log backup file, it will leave the database inaccessible, because the database is waiting for the latest transaction log backup. If you need to bring your database back to accessible and you are sure that `.bak` is the last one your need to restore, try `RESTORE DATABASE db_name WITH RECOVERY`.

So generally, the order of restoring a database:

```
Restore database name from ... with norecovery --'.bak'
Restore database name from ... with norecovery --'.dif'
Restore database name from ... with recovery --'.TRN'
```

If you are not sure if there is any `.TRN` available, you could add `RESTORE DATABASE name WITH RECOVERY` at the very end to make sure database can be accessed after restoring jobs. It wont be hurt if the database has been `restored with recovery` before or not, just a 2nd defense xD

Comment: Thanks Long, when I performed the FULL backup on my other server, it just produced that one .bak file, when I restored from it, it generated the mdf, ndf and ldf, I dont want to backup from the TRN files.

Comment: if there is only `.bak` available to be restored, then execute `RESTORE DATABASE name WITH RECOVERY`

Comment: I was just about to execute the command when I checked the progress status and the database was already restored and accessible? so from the time it completed up to 100% it took another 20m or so to be fully restored without manual intervention. is this Okay?

Comment: To be honest, I do not have similar experience before that the database would be accessible automatically after stuck in `Restoring` state for long time. I always add that command at the last to make sure database can be accessed instantly after it has been restored.

Answer (score 1):

Your `RESTORE` command has no `WITH NORECOVERY` and the default is `WITH RECOVERY`, so it was no need to execute another `RESTORE WITH RECOVERY`.

Check your SQL Server log instead. Maybe you'll find there smth like

> Recovery completed for database MyDB (database ID 5) in N
>   second(s) (analysis K ms, redo L ms, undo M ms.) This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required.

This means that even if your database was restored the database recovery was not finished yet. This happens when your db has open
 transactions at the time backup starts, so these transactions should be rolled forward/rolled back depending on whether they were committed or not at the moment backup was finished